# How to deploy several docker images to single virtual machine

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I have an application which consists of 2 docker containers. Both are small and need to interact with each other quite often through rest api.
**How can I deploy both of them to a single Virtial Machine in Google Cloud?**

Usually, when creating virtual machine, I get to chose a container image to deploy: `Deploy a container image to this VM instance`.
I can specify one of my images and get it running in the VM. Can I set multiple images?

Comment: Using Google cloud _is_ system administration.

Comment: But don't fret... ServerFault exists for these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not deploy multiple containers per VM.

Please consider this limitation when [deploying containers on VMs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers?hl=en_US&_ga=2.164023355.-566201694.1566725932&_gac=1.95535726.1573312481.CjwKCAiA5JnuBRA-EiwA-0ggPcNsK74vIL5VL5HW5uPiCcPdDwmnarGjfVlQK-4s0Kdx6WdbeGumohoCFxkQAvD_BwE):

> 1.You can only deploy one container for each VM instance. Consider Google Kubernetes Engine if you need to deploy multiple containers per
>   VM instance.
>
> 2.You can only deploy containers from a public repository or from a private repository at Container Registry. Other private repositories
>   are currently not supported.
>
> 3.You can't map a VM instance's ports to the container's ports (Docker's -p option).
>
> 4.You can only use Container-Optimized OS images with this deployment method. You can only use this feature through the Google Cloud
>   Platform Console or the gcloud command-line tool, not the API.

Comment: This answer is correct if you selected Container OS. This answer is wrong for GCE instances as you can install Docker and even setup Docker Swarm and run many containers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to deploy multi-container applications.

To achieve this on Google Cloud, you'll need:

- ssh access to VM
- docker and docker compose installed on the VM